# How to omit validation for specific record type

Tags: validation-rule

I am working on validation rule, which says,

For record type direct when we move stage to 6 contract date is required.

For record type patner when we move stage to 6 contract date is not require. The validation error should skip for partner record type

I tried this not working. Please someone help me on this.

```
(ISBLANK( Contract_date__c ) ) 
&& ( ISPICKVAL( StageName , '6-Commit/Finalizing Closure')  ) 
&& AND( RecordType.Name = "Patner_Opportunity")
```

Comment: Tags aren't meant to be used randomly. They are meant to describe what a question is about. It helps direct people with knowledge to questions they can answer, and helps people looking for answers determine if they're in the right place. This question has nothing to do with Apex, SalesforceDX, the Salesforce1-app, or "developer" ("administration" is perhaps valid, but "validation-rule" is the most correct). Please stop abusing tags.

Answer (score 1):

#### The big thing that you (and everyone else) needs to remember about validation rules

is that *they prevent Inserts and Updates when the result of the formula is **true***.

#### Brief note on syntax and style

Having `&& AND()` isn't technically a syntax error, but it should be either `&& <new condition here>` or `AND(<new condition here>)`.

Don't mix-and-match functions and operators in formulas like this. Pick one style, and stick with it. Either:

- `&&` and `||`
- or `AND()` and `OR()`

Mixing and matching makes a formula harder to read, harder to maintain, and easier to make mistakes in.

#### How to adjust your formula

If you have a formula that currently works, and you want to exclude a particular case, *you need to ensure that particular case causes your formula to result in **false***

Knowing that, when your `RecordType.Name` is "Partner Opportunity", you want the formula (currently returning `true`) to return `false`. `And`-ing an additional condition here is the right choice (every part of an AND must be true for the result to be true).

So this additional condition you need to add needs to result in `false` when the record type is "Partner Opportunity" (and that's the only part that needs to be made to result in `false`). Checking if the record type is equal to "Partner Opportunity" would result in `true` instead of false, so to exempt this record type you need to be checking when it is *not equal to* "Partner Opportunity"

The final implementation is left as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement states that the VR should be active for *direct* RecordType, but you're checking for *partner*.
By the way, it's a best practice using the `DeveloperName` instead of `Name` for RecordType, since it's unique per object and must follow [some strict rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm):

> This name can contain only underscores and alphanumeric characters, and must be unique in your org. It must begin with a letter, not include spaces, not end with an underscore, and not contain two consecutive underscores

Assuming that the DeveloperName is "Direct" (adjust it as needed) the VR should look like:

```
RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Direct' &&
ISPICKVAL( StageName , '6-Commit/Finalizing Closure' ) &&
ISBLANK( Contract_date__c )
```